# Error when trying to insert data into the table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using Android studio. I am trying to insert links into SQLite but keep on getting an error in the `boolean addData` method.

All my imports/codes appear to be correct. I am just unsure as to why I am getting these errors. Do I have to add a permission?

This is the code for the DataBase methods:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "Database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "SongList_Table";
private static final String Column0 = "ID";
private static final String Column1 ="Music Link";


public DataBase(Context context){
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);

}

public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

public boolean addData(String item){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Column1, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result <0){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Column1 + "TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

The errors:

> D/Database: addData: Adding https://www.soundhelix.com/audio-examples to SongList_Table
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "Link": syntax error
>   E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Music Link=https://www.soundhelix.com/audio-examples
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Link": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SongList_Table(Music Link) VALUES (?)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1500)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1373)
>           at com.example.mobilecomputingcw2.DataBase.addData(DataBase.java:37)
>           at com.example.mobilecomputingcw2.MainActivity.dataAdd(MainActivity.java:69)
>           at com.example.mobilecomputingcw2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22651)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6304)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

Edit: Even with after the changes to the Column1 and createTable String i am getting the same error with inserting links into SQLite.

Edit2: Turns out i just had to uninstall the app. Thanks @forpas

Edit 3: am now getting an error on the getData method

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the space in `"Music Link"`. Change it to an underscore (or any other string)

```
...
private static final String Column1 ="Music_Link";
...
```

or put quotes around it

```
...
private static final String Column1 ="\"Music Link\"";
...
```

And here

```
...
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Column1 + "TEXT)";
...
```

a space is missing before `TEXT`. It should rather be

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Column1 + " TEXT)";
```

Comment: ...or even `MusicLink` to avoid the space. (an `any other string` example as sticky bit mentioned)

Comment: @PaulT.: I deliberately  wrote "any other string" having the empty string in mind too. ;)

Comment: I get it, but sometimes simply eliminating spaces is not always a consideration to those new to the experience. No worries, I upvoted, good explanation.

Comment: Even with after the changes to the Column1 and createTable String i am getting the same error with inserting links into SQLite. Any further help will be apprietiated

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
private static final String Column1 ="[Music Link]";
```

then uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun to recreate the database.